# HashMap Remove is not working

Tags: java, android, hashmap

I've read all answers on this issue and nothing seems to be working.

Here's the code I'm running:

```
HashMap<TicketItem, ArrayList<TicketItemModifier>> items = new HashMap<TicketItem, ArrayList<TicketItemModifier>>();    
        for (final TicketItem key : items.keySet()) {
            Log.i(key.equals(item));
            Log.i(key.hashCode() + " " + item.hashCode());
        }
        Log.i(items.size());
        Log.i("C: " + items.containsKey(item));
        items.remove(item);
        Log.i("C: " + items.containsKey(item));
        Log.i(items.size());
        for (final TicketItem key : items.keySet()) {
            Log.i(key.equals(item));
            Log.i(key.hashCode() + " " + item.hashCode());
        }
```

I can't provide working code because it's really a huge project. I've gone ahead and printed everything out (as you can see in my example code) so you know the values being used by the HashMap are correct.

Log:

```
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): true
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): -823765791 -823765791
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): false
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): 1543283745 -823765791
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): false
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): 427224321 -823765791
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): false
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): -616760351 -823765791
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): 4
03-22 18:58:10.125: I/POSDoes(29790): C: true
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): C: true
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): 4
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): true
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): -823765791 -823765791
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): false
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): 1543283745 -823765791
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): false
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): 427224321 -823765791
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): false
03-22 18:58:10.130: I/POSDoes(29790): -616760351 -823765791
```

As you can see, the hash codes match, and the equals method returns true, but when printing out contains, I'm receiving true before and AFTER I call the remove method. Why doesn't this work?

**Update**

I've printed out item.equals(key) with the same result.

```
for (final TicketItem key : items.keySet()) {
            Log.i(item.equals(key));
            Log.i(key.equals(item));
            Log.i(key.hashCode() + " " + item.hashCode());
        }
        Log.i(items.size());
        Log.i("C: " + items.containsKey(item));
        items.remove(item);
        Log.i("C: " + items.containsKey(item));
        Log.i(items.size());
        for (final TicketItem key : items.keySet()) {
            Log.i(item.equals(key));
            Log.i(key.equals(item));
            Log.i(key.hashCode() + " " + item.hashCode());
        }
```

Log:

```
03-22 19:09:14.360: I/POSDoes(30458): true
03-22 19:09:14.360: I/POSDoes(30458): true
03-22 19:09:14.360: I/POSDoes(30458): 1543283745 1543283745
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): 427224321 1543283745
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): -616760351 1543283745
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): 3
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): C: true
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): C: true
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): 3
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): true
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): true
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): 1543283745 1543283745
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.365: I/POSDoes(30458): 427224321 1543283745
03-22 19:09:14.370: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.370: I/POSDoes(30458): false
03-22 19:09:14.370: I/POSDoes(30458): -616760351 1543283745
```

**Update 2**
Here is the implementation for equals()

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (!super.equals(obj))
        return false;
    if (this.getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    TicketItem other = (TicketItem) obj;
    if (!getValues().equals(other.getValues()))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

getValues() returns a LinkedHashMap with arbitrary (but equal!) values.

**Update 3**

The equals method is passing correctly (no issues). However it seems that the hash code is changing. When I call the remove function, all hashes saved inside the hash map return equal. The hash code being generated is actually just a different LinkedHashMap's hash code. Meaning the hashCode() function of TicketItem uses the hashCode() function of LinkedHashMap.

Comment: item is TicketItem and yes, I printed out both the equals method and the hashCode method to prove that there is in fact a matching hashcode.

Comment: What happens when you add a trace for `item.equals(key)`?

Comment: Can you show us the implementation of `equals()`?

Comment: You print key.equals(item). Also print item.equals(key). It has to be symmetric (and in my JDK version the version to be the way HashMap does it).

Comment: remove() returns null, because the ArrayList is null, which is ok because the initial value set is null. I've printed out what volley said, with no luck, still returns true.

Comment: Can you isolate this into a compileable example you can share, that has just the relevant portions of `TicketItem` and your test code? I have a hunch that you may discover the problem if you try and create a compileable test case.

Comment: I wish I could but the code behind TicketItem is quite extensive. My question is, if I'm receiving equal hash codes shouldn't HashMap be removing the key? Regardless of what my code looks like?

Comment: The HashMap will remove the entry if the hash code is equal AND equals() returns true (both a.equals(b) and b.equals(a)). Seems to be ok tho, given the print-outs?

Comment: `HashMap`'s `.remove()` _does_ work. What doesn't work here is either your hashcode or equals implementation. Seeing the existing code, it is quite co{nvolut,mplicat}ed, so the bug will not be obvious to spot; but we need _all_ the chain to see where it goes wrong.

Comment: What types are in `getValues()`? Do they those items have a proper `equals()` method?

Comment: HashMap.remove returns the value removed if "key" was found otherwise it returns "null". Might be worth checking?
I would expect that you get null from remove.

Comment: Start by showing the code of `super.equals()` and `super.hashCode()`

Comment: You might also want to check what you get back from items.get(key)
print it before and after the remove. If remove returns something, I would expect you to get different output when printing the item you get from "items.get(key)".

Comment: @SamuelÅslund I asked that earlier but (perhaps unwisely) deleted my comment. The OP replied that the values are `null`.

Comment: That sounds like we need test-cases for equals and hash-code.
Have you done any test-driven-development?
JUnit is your friend!

Comment: ok, following the advice from fge (and everyone else) I've made a compilable code removing a lot of things. That code seems to work, so the problem seems to be somewhere inside my other classes. Let me look around and hopefully I'll find the error.

Comment: The code for `remove()` and `containsKey()` is almost identical with respect to finding the item in the `HashMap`.  It almost sounds like your `equals()` or `hashCode()` don't return the same value every time, or some other thread is altering values behind the scenes.

Comment: @Andrew121007 Are any other threads accessing this data?

Comment: No, this method can only be accessed through the UI thread (Android's code doesn't allow me to touch this code otherwise).

Comment: @Andrew121007 Why don't you put some logging output directly in your `equals()` and `hashCode()` implementations, to show what they are returning (and what object they are being called on) just before they return? Then you can log what the `HashMap` is seeing when you call `remove()`, and identify the precise code paths being taken through your `TicketItem` implementation of those methods.

Comment: @JasonC Good idea, I'll update with this.

Comment: Android! Nice clue. Oracle's SDK checks for == in both containsKey and remove. Android doesn't. So something is wrong with respect to equals().

Comment: Had another look at the Android HashMap code. I'd say the hash of the item has changed since it was added!

Comment: @volley What about the printing methods? They're returning the same hash codes. That's what's annoying me. I'm running a for loop through the hash map and there is a hash code match, why doesn't it match in the remove method? I run the hash code checks before and after the remove and the hash codes remain untouched. i.e. true/true
1543283745/1543283745

Comment: @Andrew121007 since I don't have all info this is just guessing, but for what it's worth: the ACTUAL hash is stored in the internal hashmap. If the item had one hash when it was first added and another hash now, and both of them map to the same bucket, containsKey() would return true (due to ==) but it would never get a chance to run equals() due to hash code mismatch.

Comment: I'll elaborate in an answer.

Comment: @volley: Just out of interest, is there an online browsable source of Android's version of `HashMap`?  Or could you throw it up in a pastebin?

Comment: Ok, so I printed out when equals was accessed, and when hashCode was accessed. During the remove method, hashCode() is never ran. equals() is ran and was returned true at least once. I also traced the hashCode() method and every single time the hashCode() was never changed. I printed when added, then again printed when removed, both times they were equal. The hash code never changed. @mellamokb the best I can do is this grep code: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashMap.java

Comment: @Andrew121007: Yep I found that already.  However I'm curious about volley's comment "Oracle's SDK checks for == in both containsKey and remove. Android doesn't."

Comment: The comments are getting unwieldy... anyone want to continue this discussion on Java chat? http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java

Comment: @mellamokb I use my IDE, but this seems to show the issue: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/luni/src/main/java/java/util/HashMap.java . Compare line 335 and line 626.

Comment: @Andrew121007 I think hashCode() HAS to be run during remove(). Otherwise the HashMap wouldn't know which bucket to look in. Are you 100% sure it's not run?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say an Item is added to a HashMap with size 16. It has hashCode=20. Android's HashMap creates an entry in bucket 4, storing the actual hash (20) and a reference to the Item itself.

Now let's say the Item is modified so that the hashCode is changed to 36.

If we now run containsKey() using the same Item reference, Android's HashMap will look in the same bucket, 4. There it finds the key based on identity (==). It's the same object, but at this point it doesn't care about the hash code.

If we however run remove() using the same Item reference, Android's HashMap again looks in bucket 4. However this code does not perform the identity (==) check - it checks the computed hashCode and equals(). But since the computed hashCode has changed (20 vs 36), removal fails.

So, to sum up: The hashCode has changed since the object was added and the new hash code happens to map to the same bucket.

(Note that I find this bucket collision unlikely myself, especially given that the implementation does some magic bit operations to protect from poor hashing algorithms. There may be other explanations, but this is the only one I find logical based on findings so far.)

Comment: Seems like you're correct. However, I'm encountering weird-er bugs. When I add three items to the hash map I have the following hashes: -1149401272, 1606789343, -1472777658. Now I call the remove() function and the item that I want to remove has the hash of: 823966557. However, the remove function does a call to all other hashes, and EVERY single one returns the same 823966557.

Comment: @Andrew121007: The code for `HashMap.remove()` calls `hashCode()` and `equals()` multiple times on the key you've passed in, not on the rest of the keys.  It makes sense that the same hash code should be dumped out multiple times.

Comment: @Andrew121007 , so the hashCodes were printed as expected when the items were added. I then suspect the item class is mutable! Maybe the items are modified after having been added to the map?

Comment: @mellamokb Ah ok, that's better then. My question still stands. I am printing out the hash code of the object I'm removing and it then prints it out three more times (when I call the remove function). Why is it not removing it?

Comment: @volley I can assure you, no modification was done to this class. I generate the hashCode() AFTER all modifications are done.

Comment: @mellamokb agh now the chat is here. ;) Actually the code should only call hashCode() once, for the key passed as argument. It is then cached. Also, hash codes for existing keys are also cached.

Comment: Andrew and I are on the Java chat room (http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139/java).. can we continue the discussion there to keep out the comment clutter?

Comment: One final cent before I hit the bed (1 am here now): some implementations of equals() invoke hashCode(). In this case that would be super.equals()? Hope you solve this by tomorrow; good luck!

Comment: Thank you volley, it seems that the hashCode() function of the object was in fact changing and causing issues with the HashMap, now I know that having mutable objects in a HashMap is probably not a good idea. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Andrew121007 You can have mutable objects in a `HashMap`, as long as none of the fields that affect the hash code are mutable.